# How to create war file which refers quality and production system datasource,Using maven profiles?

Tags: maven, profiles

This is a simple service application,Which creates war file and deploy it in the CAT Application.
1.Using maven profiles,war file is builder using code:

```
 -1.1.Development environment @ my laptop, mvn <package> -P development 
 -1.2.Quality environment @ my laptop, mvn <package> -P quality 
 -1.3.Production environment @ production server, mvn <package> -P production
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.bosch.bgn</groupId>
    <artifactId>newsbox</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>newsbox</name>
    <build>
        <finalName>newsbox</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Run the application using "mvn embedded-glassfish:run" -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${glassfish.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <goalPrefix>embedded-glassfish</goalPrefix>
                    <app>D:\Java\workspace/target/${project.build.finalName}.war</app>
                    <autoDelete>true</autoDelete>
                    <port>8080</port>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!-- Instructing the resources plugin to filter certain directories -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>1.17.1</jersey.version>
        <glassfish.version>3.1.1</glassfish.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <!-- Profiles start here -->
    <profiles>
        <!-- Development environment @ my laptop, mvn <package> -P development -->
        <profile>
            <id>development</id>
            <properties>
                <db.driverClass>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</db.driverClass>
                <db.connectionURL>.....</db.connectionURL>
                <db.username>wf</db.username>
                <db.password>....</db.password>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <!-- Development environment @ my laptop, mvn <package> -P quality -->
        <profile>
            <id>quality</id>
            <properties>
                <db.driverClass>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</db.driverClass>
                <db.connectionURL>......</db.connectionURL>
                <db.username>webaccess</db.username>
                <db.password>....</db.password>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <!-- Production environment @ production server, mvn <package> -P production -->
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <properties>
                <db.driverClass>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</db.driverClass>
                <db.connectionURL>.....</db.connectionURL>
                <db.username>webaccess</db.username>
                <db.password>....</db.password>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

- I will build only one time war file using maven.
- It will deploy the
  war file in my Quality environment,after completion in my deployment
  application CAT "Q deployment completed,Start P deployment" button
     will be enabled.
- If I click the button now it has only Quality
     data-source,How to make production data-source should be
     accessed.???It should take P data-source by default for
     reference.???

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your reply.

- I used to build war file using command like - mvn package -P quality.
- It will create a war file which contains DB details of Quality system
  details copied to .properties file extension.
- Now I will enable the Q deployment via some tool by uploading the WAR
  file into the system.
- Once deployment is completed Status is "Q deployment is completed
  Start P".(This is a clickable button)
- Now if I click the button war file will be deployed in the P system.
  But the DB is Quality pointing one for P.
- Now if I access the application the System will not work.(Q DB details are there in P war file db.properties)

How to resolve this problem.???

Answer (score 0):

This will create war file for development profile:

```
mvn clean install -Pdevelopment
```

likewise for:

```
mvn clean install -Pquality

mvn clean install -Pproduction
```